# I am trying to use Filter.or in react native firebase but it gives an error 'or' not defined

Tags: firebase, react-native

I import the firestore library as in the documentation.

```
import firestore, {Filter} from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
```

It already works properly in everything else, but when I want to use Filter.or, it gives an error that 'or' is not defined.

Example use:

```
const bigCities = await citiesRef
.where(
Filter.or(
Filter.where('capital', '==', true),
Filter.where('population', '\>=', 1000000)
)
)
.get();
```

I need to use the or query in React native firebase. But when I try to use Filter.or, it always gives or 'undifined' err